# Repeated first_or_initialize conflict

Tags: mysql, rails-activerecord, amazon-aurora

I'm looking at a failure of a retried `first_or_initialize` which is "obviously impossible". Somehow, it happened even with multiple retries allowed.

The table contains columns `id` (integer primary key), `uuid` (binary) and `item_id` (integer). Both `uuid` and `item_id` have unique indexes on them.

The method should retrieve the item's uuid or create one if it doesn't exist:

```
def self.get_uuid_for(item)
  Retryable.retryable(tries: MAX_RETRIES, on: [ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique], sleep: 0) do
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction(requires_new: true) do
      item_uuid = where(item_id: item).first_or_initialize do |item_uuid|
        item_uuid.uuid = SecureRandom.uuid
        item_uuid.save!
      end
      item_uuid.uuid
    end
  end
end
```

When run locally it works:

- without existing entry (SELECT, INSERT)
- with an existing entry (SELECT)
- with competing transaction (SELECT, INSERT, ROLLBACK, SELECT)

Unfortunately at some point, the error collector received:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '22573725' for key 'index_item_uuids_on_item_id'
```

Which I'm struggling to explain. MAX_RETRIES happens to be 100, so even if somehow the association was created and deleted all the time, there's a lottery-scale chance all those retries would have actually failed.
It's not a case of the concurrent transaction taking a long time either, because in that case the INSERT for `item_uuid.save!` hangs waiting for the lock.

What scenario am I missing?

The database is MySQL / AWS Aurora 5.6. The isolation level is `REPEATABLE-READ`.